# CiviCRM_API3_Exception

Tags: extension, error, database

When I enable or disable an extension I get the error that follows. Enabling or disabling still happens. Advice on resolving this would be gratefully received. This site is running 5.21.2 on Joomla.

```
> CiviCRM_API3_Exception: "API error: Value already exists in the
> database"
> 
> #0 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Form/Extensions.php(178):
> civicrm_api3("Extension", "enable", (Array:2))
> #1 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(479):
> CRM_Admin_Form_Extensions->postProcess()
> #2 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/StateMachine.php(144):
> CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()
> #3 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Next.php(45):
> CRM_Core_StateMachine->perform(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_Extensions),
> "next", "Next")
> #4 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203):
> CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Next->perform(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_Extensions),
> "next")
> #5 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103):
> HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_Extensions),
> "next")
> #6 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(335):
> HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("next")
> #7 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php(395):
> CRM_Core_Controller->run()
> #8 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php(140):
> CRM_Core_Page_Basic->edit(32, NULL)
> #9 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Page/Extensions.php(105):
> CRM_Core_Page_Basic->run()
> #10 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(268):
> CRM_Admin_Page_Extensions->run((Array:3), NULL)
> #11 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(68):
> CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:16))
> #12 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(36):
> CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
> #13 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(121):
> CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
> #14 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(40):
> civicrm_invoke()
> #15 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/libraries/src/Component/ComponentHelper.php(402):
> require_once("/var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicr...")
> #16 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/libraries/src/Component/ComponentHelper.php(377):
> Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::executeComponent("/var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicr...")
> #17 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/libraries/src/Application/AdministratorApplication.php(101):
> Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::renderComponent("com_civicrm")
> #18 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/libraries/src/Application/AdministratorApplication.php(159):
> Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->dispatch()
> #19 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/libraries/src/Application/CMSApplication.php(196):
> Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->doExecute()
> #20 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/administrator/index.php(51): Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication->execute()
> #21 {main}  Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or
> service provider with more details about what action you were
> performing when this occurred. API error: Value already exists in the
> database Return to home page.
```

Comment: Is this a publically available extension? The problem is most likely the extension was not uninstalled cleanly - this could be due to the extension itself not doing the uninstall work required, or there might have been an error during the uninstall process.

Comment: Yes, these are pretty standard extensions, like Stripe, Mosaico & Fleximailer. I presume the issue is with the civicrm_extension table, but nothing there is obvious enough for me to see a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using CiviCase and do you have a different language than English for you CiviCRM? If so, you might suffer from a bug that has to do with the relationships for the cases. The easiest fix then is to disable the "standard" case types that are shipped with core?

Comment: That was fixed in 5.20. But worth checking.

Comment: Cool, that should be fine then....but indeed worth checking :-)

Comment: No, CiviCase is not enabled, nor is there any language apart form English installed.

Comment: Then it seems probably like Luke said, except you guessed the extension table but it's probably the civicrm_option_group/civicrm_option_value table.